# Errors When Installing MySQL-python module for Python 2.7

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

I'm currently trying to build and install the mySQLdb module for Python, but the command

`python setup.py build`

gives me the following error

`running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
error: could not delete 'build/lib.macosx-10.3-intel-2.7/MySQLdb/release.py': Permission denied`

I verified that I'm a root user and when trying to execute the script using sudo, I then get a gcc-4.0 error:

`running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1`

Which is odd, because I'm using XCode 4 with Python 2.7. I've tried the easy_install and pip methods, both of which dont work and give me a permission denied error on release.py. I've chmodded that file to see if that was the problem but no luck. Thoughts?

Comment: it looks to me like you don't have gcc installed, what OS are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that **gcc-4.0** is in your **PATH**. Also, you can create an alias from *gcc* to *gcc-4.0*.

Take care about 32b and 64b versions. Mac OS X is a 64b operating system and you should right flags to make sure you're compiling for 64b architecture.

Comment: Thanks bsnux, I ended up having to reinstall XCode and created a symlink from /ur/bin to /developer/bin. With both Python and MySQL on 64 bit architectures, I found this did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, you can use a pre-compiled installer. Check [this page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for many such installers, including [MySQLdb for various Python releases](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python)